# Relations (discrete math)

Tags: geometry, equivalence-relations

I am stuck with this problem, any help will be appreciated.

> Let $S$ be the set of all the planes in 3D, and $\alpha$ the relation on $S$ defined so that for $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2 \in S$ 
>  $\Sigma_1 \alpha \Sigma_2$ if and only if there is a line $p$ in the space such that $p \perp \Sigma_1, p \perp \Sigma_2$.
>
> Prove that $\alpha$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Hint: two planes are parallel if and only if there's a line they are both perpendicular to. Now edit your question to show how much you can do yourself, ask when you get stuck.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I don't know how to start. Does that mean that  I will define α something like: α={(Σ1,Σ2)| Σ1 || Σ2}?  Then, how do I define S? And even if I define them like this, how can I find SxS to see if α is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive,  therefore equivalence on S?
Thank you!

Comment: That's the right formal definition for $\alpha$. You don't define $S$, it's given. So is $S \times S$. Try to pay attention to the meanings rather than the formal statements. You need to show things like "if plane $P$ is parallel to $Q$ and $Q$ is parallel to $R$ then $P$ is parallel to $R$" - for transitivity. Similar statements for the other two properties.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense :) Another quick question that bothers me. The definition for reflexivity is: (∀x∈A)(x,x)∈α or in my case:
(∀Σi ∈ S | i=1...n)(Σi, Σi)∈α so, I can say that a plane is parallel with itself?

Comment: Yes. A plane is parallel with itself, if  you define parallel to include that case.. That's a little subtle, which may be why the problem was originally stated in terms of mutual perpendicularity to a line. Also: in your comment you list the planes in $S$ as if there were only $n$ of them. That's not true, and there's no need to write any kind of list. You just say "for every plane \$\Sigma$ ..." When you're all done with this exercise you can post an answer to your own question.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

We can say that *α = {(Σ1,Σ2)| Σ1 || Σ2}* and S consists every Σ in 3D. The definition for equivalence relation says that α will be equivalence if it is transitive, reflective, and symmetric. So we can prove that these three are true.

1. Transitive **(∀Σ1, Σ2, Σ3 ∈ S)(Σ1, Σ2)∈α ^ (Σ2, Σ3)∈α -> (Σ1, Σ3)∈α**
   In this case we have to prove that if *Σ1||Σ2* and *Σ2||Σ3* then *Σ1||Σ3*.
   Two planes are parallel if there is a line *p* such that *p⊥Σ1*, *p⊥Σ2*.
   So, if *Σ1||Σ2* it means there is a line p, *p⊥Σ1* and *p⊥Σ2* and because *Σ2||
   Σ3* it proves that *Σ1||Σ3*.
   So, *α* is transitive.
2. Reflective **(∀Σ ∈ S)(Σ, Σ)∈α**
   It is true because every plane is parallel with itself.
3. Symmetric **(∀Σ1, Σ2 ∈ S)(Σ1, Σ2)∈α -> (Σ2, Σ1)∈α** 
   Which is also true  because if *Σ1||Σ2* it also means that *Σ2||Σ1*

*Therefore, it is proven that α is an equivalence relation.*